# Postgres. Почему для ограничения unique создается B-tree индекс?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

По документации https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html

> Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.

По перфомансу был бы оптимален Hash index и для меня выглядит так что его функциональности достаточно для потдержания ограничения "unique". Почему в данном случае используется B-tree индекс?

Comment: Можете более подробно описать проблему, чтобы Вам быстрее помогли?

Comment: функциональности самого hash index не достаточно. Нам в любом случае надо полезть по указателю из индекса в данные, что бы проверить совпадает ли реальный ключ с тем что есть  в записи. Потому что хеши двух разных ключей могут совпадать. Кроме того если коллизий достаточно много то может оказаться что нам для проверки уникальности надо будет перепроверить несколько записей данных. Так что вопрос перформанса остается открытым.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что только для btree реализована соответствующая логика, позволяющая заявить `amcanunique`.

Если хотите погрузиться в нижележащую проблематику (либо и вовсе помочь с улучшением hash index access method) - можете начать [вот отсюда](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CANbhV-G7QLy3hP%3D6%2B%3D09OepzRPj-WgzoSZ8o2X416oxACJ1jUA%40mail.gmail.com). Дискуссионные моменты о concurency, а в основном нехватка заинтересованных людей для развития этого патча.